# Multiple views in iOS ScrollView

Tags: ios

I'm creating an iOS application, which in one of its screens, I'm using a scroll view, 
I've two view in that screen to be scrolled "black and red" views,

But, Unfortunately, when i add them to the scroll view only on of them is displayed.

The Frame of both "red and black" views are 320 W * 460 H;

This is my code "I've only the black view displayed":

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 1200)];

[scrollView addSubview:redView];
[scrollView addSubview:blackView];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES; // default is NO, we want to restrict drawing within   
//our scrollview
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are the frames of the red and black views?

Comment: @PhillipMills Sorry, i didn't catch your comment, could you clarify it in more details..?!

Comment: When you create `redView` and `blackView`, what size and location do you use for their frames?  (The concern is whether you are showing one on top of the other.)

Comment: @PhillipMills Actually, I didn't define them, so, kindly, how can i define the frames for a definite view..?!

Comment: If they exist and are visible, they have frames.  How were they created?  Put `NSLog(@"Red: %@, Black: %@", redView, blackView);" just before your call to `setBackgroundColor` and see what is printed.

Comment: @PhillipMills I've Created them as "UIView* redView;" and so as the balckview, then I've linked them to the views in the ".Nib"File, through "Connection inspector".

Comment: So, if you create them in a nib, the frame is defined by settings in the "Size inspector".

Comment: @PhillipMills Yes, They are 320 Width & 460 Height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be setting the frames for the subviews anywhere, which means their origins are both `(0, 0)`.  The views are both there, but one is on top of the other.  Set the frames to position them.